# Convert unescaped unicode to utf8 integer

Tags: string, haskell, unicode, utf-8

Firstly, I apologize if the terms "unescaped unicode" and "utf8 integer" are not correct; I don't really know what I'm talking about when I'm talking about encoding.

As a concrete example, I would like to convert the string `"\\u00b5ABC"` to the string `"\181ABC"` (`\u00b5` and `\181` correspond to `µ`). By "string" I mean `String` or `Text`.

I know how to achieve this by using a tortuous (and perhaps laughable) way:

```
import Data.Aeson (decode)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (packChars)
import Data.Text (Text)
decode (packChars "\"\\u00b5ABC\"") :: Maybe Text
```

I am ready to bet there exists a more direct way...

### Edit

Following @Alec's comment, I provide more context. In the background, there is a Javascript program that receives a character string and replaces the characters in this string by their unicode representation `\\uxxxx` *when this unicode representation is between `\u007F` and `\uFFFF`*.

On the Haskell side, I receive this new string, and I want to replace the `\\uxxxx` with their corresponding utf8 integer representations.

Comment: I feel like your problem is a bit under-specified - which characters would you like to have printed in the form `\...` and which characters would you like to be printed literally? Aside from that question, this is quite a simple problem.

Comment: honestly, your code seems like the best way. in the example you gave, you can elide the call to `packChars` if you turn on -XOverloadedStrings

Comment: @Alec Thank you for this remark. The `\u...` characters come from a Javascript program. According to my understanding, it generates these characters from `\u007F` to `\uFFFF`. Concretely, I "receive" a string containing literal characters and such `\u...` characters, and I want to replace the `\u....` characters.

Comment: @haoformayor Surprising. This looks like killing a fly with a hammer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice simple parser written using [regex-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative). First some imports and other nonsense that isn't worth reading:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe
import Numeric
import Text.Regex.Applicative

-- no idea why this isn't in Control.Applicative
replicateA :: Applicative f => Int -> f a -> f [a]
replicateA n act = sequenceA (replicate n act)
```

Now, we want to parse an escaped character. We'll use a regex that matches characters and returns a character, so it's an `RE Char Char`. Ideally I'd write it this way:

```
escaped :: RE Char Char
escaped = do
    string "\\u"
    digits <- replicateM 4 (psym isHexDigit)
    return . chr . fst . head . readHex $ digits
```

The `head` is safe because we've ensured that `readHex` will only be passed hex digits, and therefore will succeed. We can *almost* write it like that, except that `RE Char` is not a `Monad`. With newish GHC's you can probably turn on `ApplicativeDo` and be done with it, but it's not so bad to write in applicative style ourselves anyway and support all GHC's, so let's do that:

```
escaped :: RE Char Char
escaped
    =   chr . fst . head . readHex
    <$> (string "\\u"
     *>  replicateA 4 (psym isHexDigit)
        )
```

Anyway, once we have a regex for decoding a single escaped character, it's easy to produce a regex for decoding all the escaped characters and passing unescaped characters through unchanged: `many (escaped <|> anySym)`. Since this regex will always succeed, we can ignore the `Maybe`-ness of `(=~)` hedging its bets about whether an expression will match, and write

```
decodeHex :: String -> String
decodeHex = fromJust . (=~ many (escaped <|> anySym))
```

Let's try it in ghci:

```
> decodeHex "\\u00b5ABC"
"\181ABC"
> decodeHex "\\u00bABC"
"\186BC"
> decodeHex "\\udefg"
"\\udefg"
```

The advantage of writing our own parser like this instead of relying on something like `decode` is that we gain control and confidence over exactly which transformations are being done; for example, since we know `\u` will always be followed by *four* hex digits, we can only transform it when that happens, in case the original, pre-Javascript text contained `\\udefg` and we want that to appear in the final output, rather than `\3567g`; and we don't have to worry that it is trying to de-escape other things that we don't want it to do; and we don't have to "extra-escape" our string before we hand it off, either, as you do with adding the extra quotes around it. And of course, the disadvantage is that we had to engineer it ourselves, and probably have less confidence in its correctness since it hasn't been battle-hardened by a thousand users!

Comment: `replicateA` exists... in `Control.Monad`... as `replicateM`. But its constraint is still `Applicative`.

Comment: @Alec That's horrible. We have quite a bit of AMP fallout to clean up yet, it seems. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I'll try this week-end or next week. Please don't worry if I don't quickly upvote or accept the answer. This sounds very instructive.